# DNS Not working on shared subnet (2 routers)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

I am trying to setup my ISP router and my TPLink TL-WR741N router to share the same subnet.

The ISP router is connected to a fiber optic cable (Internet connection), and I'm running an Ethernet cable from the ISP router LAN 1 port to the TP-Link router's LAN 1 port. I have disabled DHCP on the TP-Link, and set its IP to 192.168.1.2 since the ISP one is 192.168.1.1.

When I connect to the TP-Link router with WiFi, I can ping other computers which are connected to the ISP router and the other way around. I can also ping all IPs. However, I can't open any web pages. I found out that the DNS is not working on the TP-Link router. That can be fixed by manually adding DNS servers in the adapter properties on Windows.

That's more like a quick fix however. Is there any other way I can fix this on router level?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that there are two places where I can add the DNS servers on the TP-Link router:

- On the DHCP settings, which are disabled
- On WAN port settings, which is also not used

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are 2 places where I can add the DNS servers. On the DHCP settings, which are disabled.  And on WAN port settings which  again is not used. (Updated the Post) And yes, I tried adding that as well. Same result.

Comment: If your clients get IP configuration settings via DHCP from one of your routers then configure your router, so that it would hand out DNS server addresses in DHCP messages.

Comment: They would normally get their DNS setting from a DHCP server. Is the "ISP router" a router or a modem? If it's a router and all of your LAN ports are bridged on both routers, the DHCP packets should travel over from the "ISP router" to any devices on the TPLink router.

Answer (score 0):

After 2-3 restarts of both routers the TP-Link router started accepting the default DNS servers specified by the ISP (all in one) router. So I guess the issue is resolved.